# What is the Time And space complexity for below solution

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, data-structures, big-o

Hi I have written the below code to find the first pair of numbers that match the sum of the target. I have a fair idea about BigO notation but I am finding it difficult in the below scenario.

```
fun twoNumberSum(array: MutableList<Int>, targetSum: Int): List<Int> {
    val end = array.size-1
    var i=0
    while(i <= end){    
        val firstNum = array[i]
        var j = i+1
        while(j <= end){
            val secondNum = array[j]
            if(firstNum + secondNum == targetSum){
             return listOf(firstNum,secondNum)  
            }
            j++
        }
        i++
    }

    return listOf<Int>()
}
```

Another solution I would think is first to sort the array and iterate over it approximately O(nlog(n)T and O(1)S.. Which one would be the optimized one?

Comment: that code is not java, please edit your question

Comment: Kotlin is similar to java and its 100% interoperable with Java and the Java community is large I would get some help from them so I tagged it as java..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *time complexity* of your code is `O(n^2)`. Here is your code:

```
val end = array.size-1
var i=0

//It should be end-1 
while(i <= end-1)
{    
    val firstNum = array[i]
    var j = i+1
   
    while(j <= end)
    {
        val secondNum = array[j]
        if(firstNum + secondNum == targetSum) return listOf(firstNum,secondNum)  
    
        j++
    }

    i++
}
```

You have an *outer loop* that runs for `n-1` times where `n` is the *length of the input array.* Lets look at how many times the *inner loop* executes:

```
 i      j
 1     n-1
 2     n-2
 3     n-3
 .      .
 .      .
 .      .
n-1     1
```

If you sum how many times the `j` loop executes, you get a function that shows the *rate of growth of function with `n`*:

```
= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n-2 + n - 1 
= (n-1)*(n-2)/2
= (n^2 - 3n + 2)/2
```

*Ignoring the constants and lower order term `3n`, since they will not matter when gets large enough.* We get a *time complexity* of `O(n^2)`.

Since you only use *three extra variables*, the *space complexity* of your code is `O(1)`.

---

The answer to your question:

> *Another solution I would think is first to sort the array and iterate
> over it approximately `O(n*log(n)T` and `O(1)S`.. Which one would be the
> optimized one?*

Yes, there exist a solution to your problem has a *time complexity* of `O(n*log n)`. It is quite popular solution. It is available online. It uses the `Two-Pointer technique`.

*The space complexity will change and it will depend on the type of sorting algorithm you use.*

---

I hope I have helped you. *Do comment you face any problems with my explanation.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.. So If I understood correctly even though every time j iterates it will decrement the size by one but still we need to consider it as O(n) 

Thanks for your explanation
O(n^2) is bad i will use soritingmethod only

Comment: @Jess You need not consider it `O(n)`. The correct thing to say is *if you `sum up` all the times the `j` loop executes for all possible value of `i`, then it lead to an expresssion which has a `n^2` term.* Hence,  `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Using backticks to format code and mathematical expressions is fine, but please don't use this for phrases, like "time complexity" or "three extra variables". This just makes your answer harder to read. I suggest you edit to improve the formatting.

Comment: @kaya3 I edited my answer to improve its readability.

Comment: @AKSingh  this is one of the well-formatted answers I have ever seen. Appreciate your time!